# Android camera has different behavior on official firmware and stock roms

Tags: android, android-camera

in my application I use the following code to access the camera:

```
camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camIntent, 0);
```

And in my onActivityForResult:

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(this);
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
ivSecondPic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
strMainPic = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
File f = new File(strMainPic);
```

This is where I get the error:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        //This line (cursor)
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
           int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }
```

Anyways, this works fine for the official software. The problem is when I try to use the camera on a device that has a stock rom installed, I get a `NullPointerException`. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** I found that the `selectedImage` is `null`. How do I get it to have the image uri? Is there something obvious that I'm missing? Obviously `data.getData()` is returning nothing. So how do I get the `Uri`?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is actually a problem. You can try with creating a file in which you will place an image before actually taking a shot with camera. Something like:

```
                filename = System.currentTimeMillis()  + ".jpg";
                filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DIR/";
                photoFile = new File(filepath+filename);
                photoUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
                intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, R.id.take_photo);
```

and then in onActivityResult:

```
            Uri selectedImageUri = null;
            String uriString = null;
            try{
                selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            }catch(Exception e){ }

            if(selectedImageUri == null){
                selectedImageUri = takePhotoUri;
                // if nothing came back insert image manually
                uriString = Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filepath+filename, filename, null);
            }
```

Comment: I will try it now and let you know

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. `intent.putExtra()` caused the `uri` on the official device to be null as well. This is turning out to be a epic headache problem.